Extracting Permission Information from the Permission Report generated from DevOps API call in PowerShell
I have downloaded a report containing permission information in JSON format using PowerShell. I need to extract the team and user details and the permission configured for each user from this report.
API endpoint used for extracting the permission report of each repository is:
"https://dev.azure.com/organizationname/_apis/permissionsreport?api-version=7.1-preview.1"
How to extract the team and user details, and the permissions configured for each repository from the downloaded report and generate a data table out of it?


Click Download detailed report for each of your target repo.



Run Permissions Report - List to get the report id of each repo.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/permissionsreport?api-version=7.1-preview.1

Run Permissions Report Download - Download to download the report.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/permissionsreport/{id}/download?api-version=7.1-preview.1

Run the following PowerShell scripts to generate the table.


# Load the JSON file
$report = Get-Content -Path '{Path to your json file}' | ConvertFrom-Json

# Create an empty array to hold the result
$result = @()

foreach ($item in $report) {
    $displayName = $item.DisplayName
    foreach ($permission in $item.Permissions) {
        # Create a custom object for each permission
        $obj = New-Object PSObject
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "DisplayName" -Value $displayName
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "PermissionName" -Value $permission.PermissionName
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "EffectivePermission" -Value $permission.EffectivePermission
        # Add the custom object to the result array
        $result += $obj
    }
}

# Output the result as a table
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File -FilePath "output.txt"

The output file looks like this:

For multiple repos, put all the Json files in the folder and read each Json file inside the folder in the outermost loop. You can filter the users or groups to be displayed in the table according to your actual needs.

Thank you it helped a lot. Can you please help me know how to get the team members of the teams displayed in DisplayName for each repo?

You can run REST API Teams - Get Team Members With Extended Properties to get a list of members for a specific team according to the team's name or id.
